# WoeUSB exit code:256 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, windows-7, woeusb

```
Installation failed!
Exit code: 256
Log:
WoeUSB v@@WOEUSB_VERSION@@
==============================
Mounting source filesystem...
Wiping all existing partition table and filesystem signatures in /dev/sdb...
/dev/sdb: 2 bytes were erased at offset 0x000001fe (dos): 55 aa
/dev/sdb: calling ioctl to re-read partition table: Success
Ensure that /dev/sdb is really wiped...
Creating new partition table on /dev/sdb...
Creating target partition...
Making system realize that partition table has changed...
Wait 3 seconds for block device nodes to populate...
mkfs.fat: warning - lowercase labels might not work properly with DOS or Windows
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Mounting target filesystem...
Applying workaround to prevent 64-bit systems with big primary memory from being unresponsive during copying files.
/usr/bin/woeusb: Line 1348: true is not set.
Resetting workaround to prevent 64-bit systems with big primary memory from being unresponsive during copying files.
Unmounting and removing "/media/woeusb_source_1537175688_12466"...
Unmounting and removing "/media/woeusb_target_1537175688_12466"...
You may now safely detach the target device
```

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9trw.png)

Comment: [Similar problem with Woeusb on Ubuntu 18.04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErTY5.png)

Answer (score 0):

GhostInTheShell upgraded WoeUSB by running the following command and now it works properly.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: I make this and nothing, but after sudo apt upgrade i get update for WoeUsb and all this now is fixed. I also recommend this software for creating bootable usb http://multibootusb.org

Comment: @GhostInTheShell Please click the gray checkmark to the left of this answer to mark it as accepted.

Comment: @karel. I tested in my installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, and failed (as before). I suggest that you describe with details how to install `woeusb` and make it work with current versions of Windows.

Comment: @sudodus I'm thinking about deleting this answer and closing its question because 1. GhostInTheShell  already installed WoeUSB and knows what to do on that point and 2. This is an answer to what is basically an abandoned question that no one will read anyway. GhostInTheShell hasn't visited Ask Ubuntu for more than 2 years.

Comment: OK, @karel, that's a good idea. But still, if ***you know*** how to make woeusb work, please post a thread (or upgrade some old post) with a detailed description.